# Moving files to new folder Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

Why isn't there any info to find in the documentation for Google Drive API about how to move existing files from the Google Drive, to a new generated directory? Isn't that possible, or are the docs from Google lacky?

Answer (score 0):

```
function FileMove(FileName) {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(FileName);
    if (!files.hasNext()) return false;
    var file = files.next();
    var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Destiny");
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.addFile(file);
    var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Source");
    var folder = folders.next();
    folder.removeFile(file)
    return true;
}
```